# After releasing my app gmail auth does not work

Tags: android, firebase

I have tested my app before releasing it, tested in "debug/release Build Variant". With the both build Gmail login was working fine. As soon as i release my app in google play store ..
I am unable to login using gmail login. I have added SHA1 and SHA256 finger print in firebase, and added respective google.serivces.json file inside app folder.

Any one can help to fix this issue?

Comment: can you paste logs ?

Comment: When you click on Gmail login what's going on ?

Comment: @TGMCians How to get the log of running apps, which has downloaded from Google play store. I dont know.. Please let me know one's...

Comment: @Arrabidas92.. When i click gmail login... It allows to press gmail id/add new gmail id.. After that it does not do any action.. Means "Intent" shouldn't call required file.

Answer (score 0):

There are two different SHA keys, debug & release.

Comment: I have added both the SHA1 finger Printa.In the release Build variant I am able to login through Gmail Auth.                                 But when i publish my app and after that if i download it and use it.. Gmail Auth is not working.. It is grey area for me..